# Memory Efficient Hashmap Alternative to Python Dictionary (Integer to Integer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-structures, hashmap

I am using a regular Python 3 dictionary to create a hashmap where both the keys and values are positive integers. The following code shows that a dict with about 6 million keys require 320 MB of memory.

```
import numpy as np
from sys import getsizeof

N = 10*1000*1000
a = np.random.randint(0, N, N)
b = np.random.randint(0, N, N)
d = dict(zip(a,b))

print('Number of elements:', len(d), 'Memory size (MB):', round(getsizeof(d)/2**20, 3))
print('Element memory size (B):', getsizeof(d[list(d.keys())[0]]))
# Number of elements: 6323010 Memory size (MB): 320.0
# Element memory size (B): 32
```

How can we create a more memory-efficient hashmap, ideally with O(1) lookup? The required hashmap can be immutable.

*In my use case, the expected size of the hashmap can be up to 2 billion. Using Python dictionaries will require an estimated 64 GB of memory. Although this still fits into memory, we will still require some memory for other processes.*

Comment: If it's possible, maybe use a list and treat the index as key?

Comment: @Arunmozhi I think that's possible. Additionally, maybe a lot of the memory usage is coming from Python representing the integers as objects instead of a true integer?

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the magnitude of those integers?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, uint32 will be sufficient.

Comment: In that case you can simply make a linear lookup table (a nump array): 2^32 * 4 are 16 GB. And lookup will be faster than with a dict. And as a free bonus you can bulk lookup.

Comment: What did you end up doing? My team is using perl hash at the moment to store around 1GB of data (2 bits per entry) and it explodes in size to 100GB atm.

Answer (score 1):

The most memory-efficient way to store key / value pairs is as a list of pair of tuples/lists, but lookup of course will be very slow (even if you sort the list and use bisect for the lookup, it's still going to be extremely slower than a dict).

Consider using shelve instead -- that will use little memory (since the data reside on disk) and still offer pretty spiffy lookup performance (not as fast as an in-memory dict, of course, but for a large amount of data it will be much faster than lookup on a list of tuples, even a sorted one, can ever be!-).

Comment: A list of tuples is not the most memory-efficient way to store key-value pairs, since it spends so much memory on tuples. It's easily beaten by a pair of lists, one for keys and one for values. Compressed options can do even better.

Comment: In fact, a dict easily beats a list of tuples in typical cases.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica What do you mean by "compressed options"?

Comment: @AthenaWisdom: I was thinking about actually applying compression algorithms to compress your data, assuming it's actually compressible and not just random like your example.

Comment: Even without compression, you can store your data in a way that has less object overhead, like NumPy arrays or serialized bytestrings holding a large number of ints' worth of data instead of one object per integer.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica , that is what i mean't when i said a list of tuples, i tested the theory of using a list of tuples, safe to say to store all the alphabet as keys for example, it takes 1176 bytes to store it as a dict as opposed to 336 for storing it as a list of tuples. I tried to do the same with numpy, but it takes 200 more bytes than a list of tuples to store them. And for your information, the amount of bytes to store both as a pair of tuples and lists, is exactly the same 336 bytes according to my tests.

Comment: @DeltaHaxor: It sounds like you just called `sys.getsizeof` on the outer list, without realizing that that doesn't count the size of the tuples (or the size of the tuple elements). `sys.getsizeof` doesn't count the sizes of objects referenced by its argument. The actual cost of the list of tuples is much higher than that.

Answer (score 1):

Given your numbers 2 * 10^9 key-value pairs of uint32 a memory addressed numpy lookup table will be hard to beat memory and speed wise as well as for sheer simplicity. The dead space will just be ~50% - roughly the same as the space you will be saving by not having to store the keys.

Comment: What is "the dead space" referring to?

Comment: @AthenaWisdom Addresses in the lookup table that do not correspond to a valid key. One would mark those with a special value.